# Only KVM Guest Should Have Access To Internet

Tags: debian, networking, routing, firewall, kvm

My setup has one server which also acts as the KVM host. Everything is built on Debian Buster, running several services for local use (networks 192.168.x.0/24). There are several wired network connections, and for security purposes I need to shield the KVM host from the web. One KVM guest though should be able to access the WWW through a wifi connection, serving developers in the DMZ of the public access network 10.0.0.0/24.

So far, everything works nicely using a bridge within the LAN, but I haven't found a hint as how to limit access to the USB-Wifi interface to that single guest only. My paranoid alter ego wants to be sure that there's no way for anybody to get access to the internal 192.x.x.x networks through the public 10.x.x.x network. Thanks for your hints in advance.

Comment: Can you describe any constraints such as a particular firewall you prefer? I am thinking an iproute2 + iptables solution would be sufficient, but it's unclear if that would work for you. Basically, the fact that it's kvm talking to some usb thingy is irrelevant: the essence of the problem is to configure your host to act as a router between two networks. Some curated output illustrating the current setup, eg `ip route` and `iptables -S`, would help, so that we're on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in -- but please note, that I do not want the host to become a router between the networks. I just want to limit one single vm to having access to the public net 10.x through an usb-wifi device. This host won't be accessable through 192.x. That's why I'm looking for a "guest accesses / owns it's own NIC" kind of answer.

Comment: Here's a schematic overview. I'm in need for a solution of the red net situation.
https://fuerstentum.net/ex/my/KVM_guest_WIFI.jpg

Comment: Looking at your picture, I think the usual way to do this is VLANs, and I think it would require rejigging the entire red network to use VLANs. I guess a VPN (maybe wireguard) could do it too. I thought you just needed to expose certain ports on the VM to the red network via the host's wireless interface, which is different to the red guest having transparent membership of the red network.

Comment: So VLANs - thanks for letting me know where to look for. Very much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't be more help. At $DAYJOB someone else takes care of all the network architecture, creating the VLANs, etc, so while I know they exist, it's not a topic I feel too strong with.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I just needed directions, not a recipe. So far things feel like I'm moving in the right direction :)